# send content to another web

Tags: javascript, loader

Let me ask what is the content of the loader.js chat file that can import content to another site if the web has imported the content as below:

[image file script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZNxi.png)

Comment: Uh what is the question? You don't expect us to show you the code of a file you know the link of do you?

Answer (score 0):

It is a JavaScript file. the content could be anything. Probably using it to keep centralised JavaScript code to be used on multiple platforms.